# How to modify mendeley's data directory

Tags: software-installation

Under win10,i can modify mendeley's data directory as following:

open regdit->HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Mendeley Ltd.\Mendeley Desktop->add a new keyvalue with a name (e.g.,datadir) and data (e.g.,"D:/Mendeley"), to transfer the mendeley database to anywhere i want.

How to do this under Ubuntu?

Comment: Check settings in its GUI, or maybe find its dot-folder (something like `~/.mendeley`).

Comment: No idea how to change it but for reference in Ubuntu the data dir is located at ~/.local/share/data/Mendeley Ltd./Mendeley Desktop/